# How do I setup Teamcity to work with SQL Server 2005 Express?

Tags: teamcity, sql-server-express

Is this possible?

I've followed the instructions from here (http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Setting+up+an+External+Database#SettingupanExternalDatabase-MicrosoftSQLServer2005) but I keep getting an 404 Error when trying to access Teamcity.

I've used the following syntax to configure jTDS:
connectionUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[host]\sqlexpress:1433/[database name]

Comment: The instance name can be defined although doesn't need to be with the port specified, although you must use double backslash to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work.

I've found this [link](http://www.acceptedeclectic.com/2008/05/visualsvn-teamcity-nant-sql-server.html) which point me to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx) JDBC driver from Microsoft.

I've put the following entries in the database.properties file:

> driverName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
>   connectionUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=TeamCity;
>   connectionProperties.user=teamcityuser
>   connectionProperties.password=password

I haven't mentioned the SQL instance name (SQLEXPRESS) anywhere.

Comment: Note that the port number defines the instance, so the name is not needed, though TCP static port is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found that reading the JetBrains documentation and cross-referencing with this blog post worked for me:

http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/Migrating-TeamCity-database-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-R2.aspx

I had to clear all the JAVA* environment variables in the command prompt I was using the run the maintainDB tool before it would work, else it was picking up the wrong JRE version or something and moaning about not having some JVM config file - I don't know, Java totally baffles me.

Also, I had to remake my SQL database with the (CS) case-sensitive collation documented by JetBrains, since we're a cross-platform team.

And TCP/IP needs enabling and a static port set.

[image: Enabled TCP and set a static port 1433 for Express]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems with that URL. First is the backslash after the forward slashes. That should not be there.

Also, make sure you can ping sqlexpress from the TeamCity server. And finally, make sure that your SQLExpress is configured to listen on port 1433 - it isn't by default. In fact, TCPIP connections in general are disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks. I've used < and > in the url and they were swallowed. I've fixed it.
The DB server is running locally and TCP/IP protocol is activated.
Any suggestion?